# Accessing to web service via network

Tags: java, android, android-ksoap2

I created an asp.net web service and using emulator I can easily access to the web service what I want now that I want to access to the web service via network so my phone will be the client and my laptop will be  server trying to do that for many hours but nothing happened still gave me `java.lang.NullPointerException`. 
I created a local network and see the picture to see the network information http://s9.postimg.org/k3a7t754f/image.png and when I connected to the network my IP address in the phone is 192.168.173.205

- this is my first class UserService this class will call the

  ```
  package com.routingware.services;    
  import android.util.Log;

  import com.routingware.database.models.User;
  import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
  import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
  import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
  import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
  import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

  public  String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
  public  String METHOD    = "";
  public  String ACTION    = "";
  public  String URL       = "http://192.168.173.1/projectnetwork/";

  public class UserService extends CommonClass {

      public UserService (String MethodName, String PageName) {
          METHOD = MethodName;
          ACTION = NAMESPACE + MethodName;
          URL    = URL + PageName;
      }

      public User CheckLogin (String Username, String Password) {

          User user = null;

          SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);

          // Send Username as parameter
          PropertyInfo Pi = new PropertyInfo();
          Pi.setName("Username");
          Pi.setValue(Username);
          Pi.setType(String.class);
          Request.addProperty(Pi);

          // Send Password as parameter
          Pi = new PropertyInfo();
          Pi.setName("Password");
          Pi.setValue(Password);
          Pi.setType(String.class);
          Request.addProperty(Pi);

          SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                  SoapEnvelope.VER11);
          envelope.dotNet = true;
          envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
          envelope.implicitTypes = true;

          envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "User",new User().getClass());
          HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
          httpTransport.debug = true;

          try
          {
              Log.e("call","1");
              httpTransport.call(ACTION, envelope);
              SoapObject Response =  (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

              user = new User();
              user.setUserID(Integer.parseInt(Response.getProperty(0).toString()));
              user.setUserName(Response.getProperty(1).toString());
              user.setUserPasswrd(Response.getProperty(2).toString());
              user.setBranchID(Integer.parseInt(Response.getProperty(3).toString()));
              user.setCompanyID(Integer.parseInt(Response.getProperty(4).toString()));
              user.setUserState(Boolean.parseBoolean(Response.getProperty(5).toString()));
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              Log.e("call",ex.toString());
              return null;
          }
          finally
          {
              return user;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- call method from AsyncTaskclass

  ```
  @Override
  protected User doInBackground(Void... params)
  {
      try
      {
          return new UserService("CheckFirstTimeLogin", "UserApi.asmx")
                  .CheckLogin(mUsername, mPassword);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          return null;
      }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute()
  {
      super.onPreExecute();
      alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this).create();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(User user)
  {
      if (user == null)
      {
          onCancelled();
          alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.login_connecnt_title);
          alertDialog.setMessage("خطأ اثناء عملية الإتصال");
          alertDialog.show();
      }
  }
  ```

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that ksoap2 using the port of http which is 80 so i want to firewall and make it open to another devices i followed the steps from here http://www.thewindowsclub.com/block-open-port-windows-8-firewall

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the logs?. Is your device connected to the same wifi network your laptop is connected. 
Snce you are using local network as your service, the device should be connected to the same wifi network.

Comment: 791-804/com.routingware.app E/call﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: this error appear when im using android simulator not my phone I dont know how to make my phone catch the error and appear it http://s1.postimg.org/ue6q1h8z3/image.png

Comment: where r u? im waiting for answer

Comment: I dont understand your question, it works in device and not working emulator. Or its not working on both?

Comment: its not working on both, but if i changed public  String URL       = "http://192.168.173.1/projectnetwork/"; to public  String URL       = "http://10.0.0.2/projectnetwork/"; it will work just in emulator